# Effect of illness on vocal range

Tags: health, vocal-range

My usual vocal range is F2-A4. During a recent illness, my range was temporarily reduced to F2-C4. Why does throat irritation seem to affect only my high notes?

Comment: Strange, sometimes it would even expand my range. :/ Sometimes shrink.

Answer (score 1):

Probably due to thickening of the vocal chords due to swelling.  I've often found that when I get a throat problem, my range is lower.  I can't hit my highest notes and can hit lower notes than usual.  (I'm a rather high baritone, by the way; I've sung lead in a barbershop quartet and second tenor in a choir.)